# Can React Native Track-Player play url without .mp3 extension?

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli, react-native-sound, react-native-track-player

I am working in React Native and I want to ask you that can we play the song without having .mp3 extension in the track url.

Suppose I have url like this https://open.spotify.com/track/0pqnGHJpmpxLKifKRmU6WP can I somehow play the song in react-native?

I tried using React-Native track player but it is not playing the song.